# How to use conditional "if" in this situation?

Tags: conditional-constructions

Which one of those 2 versions is the corrent one?
1. "If I wanted to tell you who I am, I'd have done it already."
2. "If I had wanted to tell you who I am, I'd have done it already."

Answer (score 2):

I believe both sentences to be correct.

1. **Unreal condition in the present with an unreal past result**:

*If - past simple, would have + past participle*

> **If** I **wanted** to tell you who I am, I **would have done** it already."

2. **Unreal condition in the past**:

*If - past perfect, would have + past participle*

> **If** I **had wanted** to tell you who I am, I **would have done** it."

Comment: There is no need to leave out *already* in the second sentence. They are both fine as they are.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most common use would be:

> If I wanted to tell you who I am, I'd have done it already.

Answer (score 0):

The first would be the correct one, as implies more present tense, i.e. a current wanting.

> If I wanted to tell you who I am, I'd have done it already.

The second version could also be correct, but being based in the past, wouldn't require the word "already":

> If I had wanted to tell you who I am, I'd have done it.